# Blurry image from Illustrator to Word

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, microsoft-word

I am saving a logo from Illustrator and my client wants to import it into word. I save the file as a .pdf as been told by this sight and the image comes into word slightly blurry but blurry enough that it looks unprofessional. Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator select the logo and copy it. Paste it in Word using Paste Special.

In Paste Special dialog box choose Picture (Enhanced Metafile). The Enhanced Metafile format can contain both raster than vector images.

This is the only way to insert vectors in Word (and other Office applications). You will be able to resize it without loss of quality.

In Illustrator you can save the logo in EMF format using File > Export and choosing the EMF extension.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2011/06/28/emf-file-overview/

Answer (score 0):

It's actually always best to use RGB raster files for Word.

Yes, Word *claims* to support eps or wmf and you *can* insert those formats. The problem is, unless you know how to deal with Word randomly having issues with those formats, they can be problematic.

For a client with little or no graphical sense, export your Illustrator logo as a PNG with transparency. Export it at a fairly large size, then reduce it once it has been inserted into Word.